# How can I use PerfectScrollbar in Angular to scroll to top on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

How to Scroll to top on event click using perfect-scrollbar in angular?

I have tried every solution available on google. but still facing issue, the issue is that I am accessing perfect-scrollbar through viewChild e.g but cant find any scrolltoTop function
in ts:

```
 @ViewChild('SideBarPerfectScroll') SideBarPerfectScroll: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
```

```
and on click:reset(){ this.SideBarPerfectScroll.scrollToTop(0, 1); }and in HTML:<perfect-scrollbar id="pss"  #SideBarPerfectScroll="ngxPerfectScrollbar" style="margin-top: -10px;" class="scroll-container"><div class="card shadow-none p-0 m-0 sideBarSide">MyList
```

version in package.json
ngx-perfect-scrollbar ^10.1.0
angular version 14